# Simpledateformat is not giving proper date

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I want today's date in my application to store it in a database as a string but when i used simpledatefromat and calender.getInstance(), it's not giving me proper date. The code is as below.

I tried simpledateformat's another constructor which takes locale as parameter but still not showing proper date

```
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        String dateF = dateFormat.format(date);
```

expected date should be 21-04-2019
actual result 21-26-2019

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Answer (score 0):

To get the month like the way that you want, you need to change "dd-mm-yyyy" to "dd-MM-yyyy"

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
String dateF = dateFormat.format(date);
```